# Разница дат и времени в Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Как подсчитать разницу даты и времени в excel?

Если вычислять разницу 2018-01-09 **15:24:05** и 2018-01-08 **20:06:25**, то пишет только время,  а если отнимать **2018-01-10** 15:24:05 и **2018-01-08** 20:06:25 то пишет 1 дней и время.

Я так понимаю, такое внутренними средствами *Excel* это не сделать? 
Пробовал через

```
=ТЕКСТ(B4-B3;"ч:мм:сс")
```

Если разница только во времени, то все как положено считает и выводит только разницу во времени, а если будет разница превышающая 24 часа или один месяц?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно Вас понял - то может что-то типа такого?

```
=ЕСЛИ((B4-B3)<1;ТЕКСТ(B4-B3;"ч:мм:сс");ОКРУГЛВНИЗ(B4-B3;0)&"дн. "&ТЕКСТ(B4-B3;"ч:мм:сс"))
```

Comment: спасибо, то, что нужно

Comment: Вместо округления можно *ЦЕЛОЕ(B4-B3)* и перенести условие::  *=ЕСЛИ(B4-B3<1;"";ЦЕЛОЕ(B4-B3)&"дн. ")&ТЕКСТ(B4-B3;"ч:мм:сс")*

Answer (score 1):

Дата в *Excel* - число дней от 01.01.1900г., время - дробная часть числа. Например, *10.01.2018  10:15:20* в числовом выражении будет *43110,4273148148* (выражение даты в десятичном формате можно посмотреть, задав формат ячейки *Общий*).

Т.к. дата - число, то перевод ее в текстовый формат нежелателен - не всегда тестовое представление преобразуется в число, а это чревато ошибками или невозможностью применения полученного значения для дальнейших вычислений.

```
=B4-B3
```

Визуально показать требуемое можно с помощью формата ячейки (задать в закладке "*все форматы*"):

```
ДД "дн." чч:мм:сс
```

Значение дата/время сохранено в числовом формате. Недостаток: формат отобразит количество дней не более 31

Но дата/время текстом также применяется (например: в конечных документах, для отображения значения в составе другого текста):

```
=ТЕКСТ(B4-B3;"ДД "" дн. "" чч:мм:сс") 

=РАЗНДАТ(B3;B4;"y")&" лет. "&РАЗНДАТ(B3;B4;"ym")&" мес. "&РАЗНДАТ(B3;B4;"md")&" дн."&ТЕКСТ(B4-B3;"чч:мм:сс")
```

Comment: за форматирование - спасибо. Если применяю форматирование с годами то выдает 01 месяц и подсчитанное время, почему так? В текстовом варианте считает правильно.

Comment: @Pavel Fedorov, извините, форматы с месяцем неправильные. Нулевой месяц принимается за январь. И не только это: При переходе количества за полный месяц формат покажет +1 месяц. Удалил ошибочные форматы.